# CollectionView Scroll to last item .net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Quiero saber como puedo codificar para cuando vea una collection se vaya el scroll al ultimo item de la lista desde el viewmodel, estoy usando C# y .net MAUI

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no entendi tu problema.. que viewmodel? si estas usando maui, que control? donde estas guardando la coleccion?